# Access to variables in fluid_styled_content partials

Tags: typo3, typo3-10.x, fluid-styled-content

I have cloned the file `sysext/fluid_styled_content/Resources/Private/Partials/Media/Type/Image.html` into my own template directory and set the constant to use that path. **This works fine**.

Now I want to output the "source" metadata of the image (which you can edit from the files list or some other places) additionally.

In debug output of `{file}` I can see this data under the branch `{file.originalFile.metaDataAspect.source}`.

But if I want to use this data to output there comes an error message `Cannot access private property TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\File::$metaDataAspect`.

How can I access this data in my modified fluid_styled_content template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data are stored inside the properties of an array not(!) shown by `<f:debug>{filereference}</f:debug>`.

The data come from the system extension "filemetadata". One can access the file metadata by using `{filereferce.properties.source}` or any other detail you want. You can get a list of all provided properties by using `<f:debug>{filereference.properties}</f:debug>`

Source: [Using FAL in the Frontend](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/10.4/en-us/ApiOverview/Fal/UsingFal/Frontend.html#get-file-properties)

Answer (score 0):

The chapter "[Get File Properties](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-fal/8.7/en-us/UsingFal/Frontend/Index.html#get-file-properties)" of the File Abstraction Layer documentation is telling:

> If you have a file reference and want to get its properties like Metadata, you have to access “originalResource” first. Example:

```
{filereference.originalResource.title}
{filereference.originalResource.description}
{filereference.originalResource.publicUrl}
```

So, for the property "source", the following should work:

```
{file.originalFile.source}
```

Comment: This does not work. There are no properties like ```{filereference.originalResource.title}```. I tried it with ```{filereference.originalFile....}``` but it does not work too. I used the newer docs https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/10.4/en-us/ApiOverview/Fal/UsingFal/Frontend.html